# Install Redis on Windows Server

Tags: windows, redis

I am trying to install Redis on my windows Server 2012 R2. The problem is that all the installation guides that I have found are out-of-date.

Can anyone show me the easiest and most recent way to install Redis on Windows?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this guide for my setup, hopefully will work for you to

https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows#running-microsofts-native-port-of-redis

Comment: What was your windows version? and did it work for you?

Comment: Please note that Microsoft didnt support theirs fork anymore, from github repo: "This project is no longer being actively maintained. If you are looking for a Windows version of Redis, you may want to check out Memurai. Please note that Microsoft is not officially endorsing this product in any way."

Answer (score 4):

here is the quick start from powershell:

1. install the Chocolatey package manager:

   `iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`
2. use chocolatey to install redis
   `choco install -y redis-64`

   3. run the server:
      `redis-server`

Comment: Is Chocolatey package manager suitable for production environments?